# Fedora 38 не загружается с live cd

Tags: linux, grub, fedora

При запуске fedora 38 с usb виснет на чёрном экране с белой полоской.
Записывал образ через fedora media writer, etcher, Rufus. Пробовал nomodset и загрузку в консольном режиме. Secure boot и fast boot отключены. Ошибка остаётся.
Конфигурация ПК:
Asus maximus vii hero
I7 6700
Gtx 1060 6gb
зависание[image: зависание]

зависание с отключением quiet в режиме nomodeset[image: зависание 2]

Comment: скорее всего, никакого «зависания» нет, а система отлично функционирует. ну, за исключениме x-сервера. уберите все попытки задействовать навороченные режимы gpu, и будет вам и картинка на мониторе.

Comment: Не подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: интернеты полны этой информации, как королевские ночные горшки. запрос к вашему любимому поисковому сервису вида «linux не стартует графика» даст вам множество вариантов параметров для передачи программе linux.

Comment: кстати, начинать можно было и с чтения инструкции по установке. там в частности упомянуто, что можно не ковыряться самому с выдумыванием параметров, а выбрать уже готовый набор: в меню загрузки пункт «troubleshooting», далее «start бла-бла in basic graphic mode»: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f36/install-guide/install/Booting_the_Installation/

Comment: Уже выбирал, всё равно стопается на этом месте

Comment: скачал я iso, вижу, что предлагают там в качестве «basic graphic mode» `vga=791`. можно ещё понизить планку: `vga=normal` (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/svga.rst). ну а можно на немного другие вещи попытаться повлиять (это если следовать моему второму комментарию): всякие там `acpi=off`, `noapic`, `nolapic` и т.д. и т.п.